# KerasClassifier inside new class not functioning correctly

Tags: keras

I am using KerasClassifier to create a NN, usually, after using .fit() the object will still retain type of wrappers.scikit_learn.KerasClassifier and then further functions such as cross_val_score and GridSearchCV work perfectly. I am now trying to fit my code into a format that I have been given for a project which has a predefined class to hold the NN. When trying to assign either this new class or a property of the class with the KerasClassifier wrapper type the return from .fit() is instead of type engine.sequential.Sequential meaning the further functions will not operate.

I would expect the .fit() function to return an item of type KerasClassifier.

The code below is passed preprocessed training data.

```
class Module4_Model:

    def __init__(self):
        self.my_model = None

    def init_classifier(self):
        self.my_model = KerasClassifier(build_fn = self.build_classifier,
                             optimizer = 'adam',
                             n_units = 7,
                             batch_size = 32,
                             epochs = 100)
        return self.my_model

    def build_classifier(self, optimizer, n_units):
        self.my_model = Sequential()
        self.my_model.add(Dense(units = n_units, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu', input_dim = 15))
        self.my_model.add(Dense(units = n_units, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))
        self.my_model.add(Dense(units = 1, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'sigmoid'))
        self.my_model.compile(optimizer = optimizer, loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
        return self.my_model

    def train_model(self, X_train, y_train):
        history = self.my_model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_split = 0.1)
        print(type(self.my_model))
        return history

my_model = Module4_Model()

my_model.init_classifier()

history = my_model.train_model(x_train_processed, y_train_processed)
```

The same code moved outside of a class works as expected.

Comment: So you want to make your `train_model` return your `self.my_model`?

Comment: Why are you using self.my_model for two things? There is no need to use a class variable in build_classifier, this is probably the problem

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro - The aim is to use `self.my_model` to hold the KerasClassifier. Unfortunately, I've been given a template to follow which requires the KerasClassifier to be placed in this property of self. Annoyingly, I have a model that works when not using the class but that doesn't quite work with the template to work in! The idea of the template is that parameters for standardising and encoding data can also be saved within the `Module4_Model` class, I've removed these parts for simplicity on here.

Comment: @Yoskutik - `train_model` is used to train the KerasClassifier using the `fit` function. Before `train_model` is called `my_model.my_model` is of type KerasClassifier, however, the `fit` function returns an object of type Sequential. It is this part that is confusing me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the same variable (`self.my_model`) inside both `init_classifier` and `build_classifier`, which is not necessary at all. When the `KerasClassifier` instance is created, it received `self.build_classifier`, which is called each time a new classifier instance is created (inside `KerasClassifier`), and then it overwrites the value of `self.my_model`.

A simple solution is to do this:

```
def build_classifier(self, optimizer, n_units):
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Dense(units = n_units, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu', input_dim = 15))
        model.add(Dense(units = n_units, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))
        model.add(Dense(units = 1, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'sigmoid'))
        model.compile(optimizer = optimizer, loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
        return model
```

Just do not use the same variable for two purposes and it should be fine.

Comment: Thanks very much for the quick response. That makes a huge amount of sense and works perfectly. My apologies for my ignorance in my first response, I didn't understand what you were saying. This works great now!